# Custom .deb does not install all files

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dpkg, packaging

I'm developing a proprietary cross-platform file manager called [fman](https://fman.io). I want to distribute it to Ubuntu users as a `.deb` file, which can be downloaded from my web site. I use `fpm` to create this file, which works without problems.

When the user installs fman, I want to add a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which points to my update server. This would allow the user to automatically update fman via Ubuntu's package manager (or via `apt-get`).

I did the obvious: I placed the file inside the `.deb` archive under `etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list`. The problem is: This file is not created under `/etc/apt/...` when the user installs fman from the `.deb` file.

When I do `dpkg -x fman.deb some_dir/`, the file `fman.list` is correctly created at `some_dir/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list`. Likewise, when I do `dpkg-query -L fman` after installation, I do get the output

```
/.
/etc
/etc/apt
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list
...
```

I don't get any errors or warnings when I install the `.deb` file from the command line via `sudo dpkg -i fman.deb`. I tried increasing the log level via `sudo dpkg -D 100 -i fman.deb`. The only two lines of output pertaining to `fman.list` are:

```
D000100: setupvnamevbs main='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list' tmp='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list.dpkg-tmp' new='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list.dpkg-new'
D000100: setupvnamevbs main='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list' tmp='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list.dpkg-tmp' new='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list.dpkg-new'
```

At some previous point, I found a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list.dpkg-dist`. But that file was removed when I uninstalled fman. Subsequent installations of fman did not produce the file again.

Does anybody know why `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list` is not created when I install fman from a `.deb` file?

Comment: I just checked to make sure that `fman.list` isn't empty - it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

I tested my `.deb` file via cycles of the following two commands:

- `sudo dpkg -i fman.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -r fman` (equivalently, `sudo apt-get remove fman`)

I found out that `... -r` excludes config files. To also delete config files, one must use `sudo dpkg -P fman`.

During my testing, I must have manually deleted `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fman.list` at some point. But `dpkg` (/`apt`) still remembered that it had installed that file, so it didn't re-install it the next time I did `dpkg -i` (equivalently, `apt-get install`).

The solution was therefore to call `sudo dpkg -P fman`. The next time I then did `dpkg -i fman.deb` the `fman.list` file was created as expected.